# How can I export multiple methods of the same function from submodules within my module?

Tags: julia

What’s the right way to export all the methods of `thing` from the submodules here (this doesn't work):

```
module Foo

module Bar
thing(x::String) = 1
end
import .Bar: thing

module Baz
thing(x::Int) = 1
end
import .Baz: thing

export thing
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to make them the same function. `thing` can't mean two different things in the same namespace.

For instance:

```
module Foo

function thing end

module Bar
import ..thing
thing(x::String) = 1
end

module Baz
import ..thing
thing(x::Int) = 1
end

export thing
end
```